# How to use a Matrix with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, graphics, web, svg, raphael

I would like to move a RaphaelElement and created a simple test case:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
var rect = paper.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
rect.attr("fill", "blue");
rect.matrix.translate(300, 300);
```

But the rectangle isn't moved. At first I thought that for the matrix was probably not updated correctly and tried this:

```
//...
alert("" + rect.matrix.x(0,0)); // prints 0
rect.matrix.translate(300, 300);
alert("" + rect.matrix.x(0,0)); //prints 300
```

Obviously the matrix is changed but the rectangle does not care about that. Therefore I changed my code to:

```
 rect.matrix=rect.matrix.translate(300,300);
```

But that either crashes the program or has no effect at all.
It seems like I'm missing some sort of update method, to apply a matrix to a RaphaelElement. Something that looks like this:

```
rect.updateMatrix();
```

I've searched in the documentation but didn't find such a method. What is the canonical usage of matrices in RaphaelJs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rect.translate(300, 300)` will apply a translation or alternatively [`rect.transform("t300,300")`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.translate)

Also

```
rect.transform(['m',mat.a, mat.b, mat.c, mat.d, mat.e, mat.f]);
```

can be used to apply an existing matrix (mat) to the rect.

Comment: rect.translate is deprecated and rect.transform accepts a string. Since there will be a lot of movement in my application I wanted to avoid using transform. Why would they offer matrices, if they aren't usable ?

Comment: Hey, I just realised that you've answered my other question, too. On how to apply a transform in Raphael. You offered matrices as a solution. Could you post some code, how you would move a RaphaelElement using a matrix ? That would be great

Comment: I think matrix is read-only and I suspect it's the consolidation matrix for the transform on the element.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to replace the transform method by using matrices ?

Comment: rect.transform("m1,2,3,4,5,6") or perhaps you need to ask a clearer question.

Comment: With that code, I need a matrix "literal". How can I use a given matrix. Supposing you have a matrix object named mat. How do you apply it to a RaphaelElement elem ?

Comment: rect.transform(['m',mat.a, mat.b, mat.c, mat.d, mat.e, mat.f]);

Answer (score 0):

I found another reference on Stackoverflow that does an awesome job explaining the matrix. It solved my problem.

[StackOverflow Matrix clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939195/what-is-a-matrix-for-in-raphael)