# Raphael.js get Positions of Individual Elements in a Set after Rotation

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a set of points and lines. The points are simply circles and are important for me to track their positions. If I rotate my set, all elements within the set change position on the canvas. I need to be able to retrieve the position information for each point. If I go to my point and do `point.attr('cx')`, I can see that nothing has changed. I tried one method where on the point I call `var bb = point.getBBox()` and this seems to pull the updated point but if I try to set the updated point information on the given point like `point.attr('cx',(bb.x + (bb.width / 2))` this is causing my object to move what appears to be the same rotation; so my 15 degree becomes a 30 degree rotation. (I think that is what happens but not sure) I noticed also I can console.log an object and see a point.attrs.cx and it does not update either so I took a shot at manually updating it instead and it caused other odd behaviours. I know this is difficult to follow without seeing it but maybe if there is some general information or some best practice for manipulating a set and making sure you can track the objects within; seems like something that should be built in; but maybe there's a way to easily add it in. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with... the call `getBBox()` gets new coordinates which get updated to each point's attributes. The call to `transform()` is my missing piece and the key to answering my question. It resets the transformation data on the object so the point position can be true to coordinates of the canvas.

```
for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
     var bb = tools.points[i].getBBox();
     points[i].attr('cx',bb.cx);
     points[i].attr('cy',bb.cy);
     points[i].transform('1 0 0 1 0 0');
}
```

Thanks to the following post for a better understanding of SVG transformations https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/ 
I also gleaned some good information from this post.
[What is a "matrix" for in raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939195/what-is-a-matrix-for-in-raphael)